How does a Christian soul fit in with known facts?
We know from many sources of evidence that life started more than 4 billion years ago, and over the aeons evolution produced a huge range of different creatures. We also know that modern humans originated at least 200,000 years ago, and that for at least 50,000 years humans have had the same cognitive powers as current ones.
The theory of evolution also tells us that there never was a "first couple". Instead, the genes that make us human spread through a population of almost-humans, and the change from almost-human to fully-human happened over a period of tens of thousands of years, with no clear speciation point.
Among Christians, many accept evolution and the age of the earth as facts. However, most of them also agree that, somewhere along the line, we acquired a soul - which they argue is the final piece that makes us fully human. For example, Catholics believe that "after a long and gradual process of biological evolution, which produced hominins who were highly advanced mentally, there was a sudden transition, in which God raised some of them to the “spiritual” level, i.e. to the level of rationality and freedom".
I can see 2 possibilities here: either God implanted a soul in just one couple ("Adam and Eve"), or He gave souls to all humans alive at the time. Either way I see problems.
If all people got souls, how do you explain the original sin, for which Jesus had to die on the cross? Did all those people commit the same sin? In that case, why was God complaining? He obviously built the same mistake into all people. If God built the same mistake into all people, He should not complain about it, and accept His mistake.
Which leads me to the other alternative: if only one couple got a soul (or the soulless ones died out), and we are all descended from that one couple, how do you square that with DNA evidence? Our DNA shows no evidence at all of the human species ever having been restricted to just 1 couple.
How do Christians reconcile the existence of the soul with the fact of evolution, and specifically the DNA evidence?
EDIT
I just realised there's a third alternative: God gave a soul to Adam & Eve only, and all the "soulless" ones survived as well. That explains who Adam's children had offspring with. However, it also means that the vast majority of people today are direct descendants of the soulless ones, and hence cannot have a soul. That is contrary to all Christian teaching.

What is a soul?

@user80226 I want to know how Christians circumvent the conundrum caused by the scientific evidence, specifically the DNA evidence against Adam & Eve.

You haven't shown a 'conundrum' since you have not cited real evidence. There is not a single substantiated fact in the question. It states that opinions are held by un-quoted and un-referenced others. The fact is that I am going to die. And I want to be saved from that death.

Evolution is not a fact, it is a theory and theories never become facts.  The fact is biodiversity and evolution is a theory attempting to explain that fact.  There is no end to the conundrums which arise once the Biblical text is supplanted by human theories.  IMHO, Christians shouldn't attempt to reconcile conundrums manufactured by disbelief in Scripture.

You might as well ask how atheists reconcile their theory of history with the "known fact" of Noah's voyage on the ark.

@NigelJ "The fact is that I am going to die. And I want to be saved from that death." Talk about contradicting yourself. Anyway, I don't need to provide evidence for my question. You need to provide evidence (not opinions) for your answers,

This site is about Christian doctrine not how random Christians reconcile science, philosophy and theology. I don't think there is no generic Christian doctrine of a soul, if anything, I think that's a philosophical idea Christianity adopted from Plato.  Also your citation about Catholics isn't doctrine, it is simply something Catholics are permitted to believe as the Church doesn't have a definitive doctrine on evolution (or lack thereof)

Nevertheless, I think this is a good question, just one that we can't answer (I mean, you're gonna get answers, but they're simply going be either people's opinions or their best guess at what their denomination teaches)

Closed because it's "opinion based". Unlike the way people "interpret" the bible to suit their opinions.


We know from many sources of evidence that life started more than 4 billion years ago

No, we don't. There are many lines of evidence that indicate the Solar System is less than a million years old, perhaps only thousands. What are these supposed sources as mentioned above? There are only two; first, we can see distant light, and second, much radioactive decay has occurred.
To the former, there are solutions to Relativity that don't require Earth to be billions of years old. Second, the Cosmic Microwave Background is too uniform (see Horizon Problem) for standard models, indicating that we don't actually how energy (light, etc.) has propagated throughout the universe. Third, the idea that distance equates to age means we should see recognizable "age" differences between nearer and more distant features, and we don't. At best, this is circumstantial evidence; it isn't conclusive.
To the latter, there is all manner of evidence from geology and paleontology that radioactive decay has undergone one or more periods of significant acceleration. Some of these evidences are direct (e.g. systemic inconsistencies, wrong "dates" for rocks of known age, effects which directly result from accelerated decay), while others point to ages that contradict radiometric dates (e.g. 14C presence in things supposedly much to old to retain any 14C, polystrate fossils, preserved DNA and soft tissues, many various evidences that the majority of the rock layers were deposited over a short period). In short, while the conclusion of "long ages" is the most natural one from the observation that much decay has occurred, it isn't sustainable when the totality of evidence is considered.

The theory of evolution also tells us that there never was a "first couple".

The so-called "theory" of evolution (or more accurately, Common Descent) is similarly problematic. One of the problems was stated just a sentence earlier; there is no increase in human cognitive abilities. Mutations are, on balance, harmful, and recent observations clearly indicate that overall "fitness" of most species is degrading. Mathematical models indicate that even the postulated "long ages" (which we just invalidated anyway, and without which, the junk hypothesis of "evolution" is a non-starter) are vastly insufficient to supply the quantity of genetic information that is observed. Long term observations have repeatedly shown that mutations are extremely limited in their ability to produce "novel" information (confirming the mathematical models which exclude mutation as a viable mechanism for producing life as we observe it). The fossil record is not consistent with Common Descent (the Cambrian explosion is especially problematic), nor does it provide the required transitional forms.
To be sure, Natural Selection is certainly observed. Moreover, the rate of natural selection is actually much more rapid than predicted by Common Descent. However, natural selection acts on existing genetic information; it does not create new information, but often discards existing information. Natural selection is responsible for turning a canine ancestor into modern dogs, wolves, coyotes, dingoes, etc., all of which can interbreed, but it is not capable of turning a canine into anything other than a canine.

Our DNA shows no evidence at all of the human species ever having been restricted to just 1 couple.

Actually, Y-chromosome evidence suggests a single common ancestor about 4,500 years ago, from which three branches descend. Mitochondrial evidence indicates a single common ancestor about 6,000 years ago. While this seems contradictory, it actually correlates perfectly with Eve as the female ancestor and Noah as the male ancestor (because, while Noah is descended from Adam, Noah and his sons — three of them — were the only male survivors of the Flood).
Nathaniel Jeanson has done much notable research in this area, though it should be noted that the mitochondrial studies are from others.

How do Christians reconcile the existence of the soul with the fact of evolution, and specifically the DNA evidence?

As I hope I've shown, "the existence of the soul" isn't the problem. The problem is that you've been tricked, by humans desperate to deny what Paul clearly teaches in Romans 1 in order to rationalize their sinful desires, into believing false "science". This is indicated by your description of the unproven and highly problematic "theory" of evolution as a "fact". Observations are facts; explanations in real science are never facts. The use of "fact" to describe Common Descent isn't science, it's propaganda.
The revealed Word of God, who cannot lie, tells us True history; that the Earth was created about 6,000 years ago, that animals were created, and reproduce, after their "kinds", that all living humans are descended from two people (Adam and Eve) and from eight people (Noah, his wife, his three sons, their wives), and that Earth was reshaped by a catastrophic, global Flood about 4,500 years ago. Real science confirms Scripture over and over again.
Obviously, I don't have the space here to go into these topics in depth; thousands of pages, maybe even millions, have been written on these matters. There are many other Questions here that deal more directly with the historicity of Genesis and many resources are available both online and in (physical) print. If you're willing to give genuine consideration to these matters (as opposed to simply ranting against them) and would like more information, I host a chat room that focuses on Creation Science and related matters.

Very good treatment. +1

Excellent research. Best I have seen to date. Up-voted +1.

A 6,000 year age of the earth has about as much evidence as the Flat Earth theory. Or maybe the FE theory is correct. After all, the Bible strongly implies that it is indeed flat. The ONLY evidence for both theories is the Bible. Both contradict all other evidence

And your statement about the ages of Y chromosome Adam and Mitochondrial Eve contradicts everything science has to say about that. In other words, you just made that up. I suggest you do some more research.

@hdhondt, no, Scripture doesn't imply Flat Earth. As for there being no evidence, that's just flat wrong; maybe you should do more research. Here's a start: Gibbons, "Calibrating the Mitochondrial Clock". It's not the only paper, either (Jeanson, who I already mentioned, cites others, as well as his own Y chromosome work). "Science" has a pronounced tendency to ignore or twist findings that don't fit the "billions of years" paradigm. Lake Missoula is an excellent case in point that has been (grudgingly) accepted.

@hdhondt, also, saying that "[I] just made that up" is a) ad hominem, b) blatantly false (none of the above claims are mine originally), and c) probably in violation of this site's CoC. I challenge you to show one single claim that is "made up", as I can assure you, all of them are evidence backed. I also challenge you to consider whether your beliefs are reliable when "you just made that up" is your first line of defense.

Re FE, look up Matthew 4:8-9 and explain how that is possible unless the earth is flat. And, I notice you don't back up your claims either.

@hdhondt, the earliest manuscripts don't include a mountain. More likely what Jesus saw was a) a map, b) a vision of some sort, or c) miraculous. See https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/earth/falling-flat-earth/ for more rebuttals. As to sources, I already cited some. See also Whitcomb, Morris, Snelling, Wise (geology) and just about anyone associated with the Discovery Institute, among others (biology). See other Questions or ask in chat if you want specifics.

Thanks for giving me another interpretation of the bible. If it's the literal word of god, should you not take it as it is? And how about the 2 genealogies of Jesus. And don't give me the "interpretation" that one of them is the descent via Mary.

Regardless of ones scientific theories which can’t be proven but remain only a theory there is one logical truth that seems logical even with the unproven assumptions of evolutionary theory:  All humans as they exist today did have a single set of parents whose children  encompass the whole current population.  If there was not an original male and female that produced a human similar to us, but instead different evolutionary branches of previous organisms coincidentally arriving at the current human state existed (without any fossilized proof),then one would expect significantly different kinds if humans today. However the human race is very uniform. This means the current population had single parents that can be called Adam and Eve, and these parents had a soul that sinned and whose guilt were transmitted to all their posterity.
The only difference with creationism that denies evolution is that Adam was created out of the dust of the earth and eve from his rib and were not the result of a long evolutionary process from less complex organisms.

DNA evidence rules out a "first pair". Our DNA does show that the human population was down to a few thousand around 70,000 years ago. And, as I said in my question, evolution does not work the way you seem to think. As an example, chickens were bred from Asian Jungle Fowl some 3,000 years ago. However, at no stage was there a "first chicken". A species population just gradually flows and changes.

@hdhondt - I don’t put any faith in someone’s DNA theory.  Basic logic is more persuasive to me.

I assume you do accept it if the courts condemn someone on the basis of DNA evidence.

@hdhondt - Sure. I assume you do not have a DNA sample of Adam. Therefore there is no equivalency of subjects. One is science, one is a scientific religion and philosophy. I like hard science myself.

Yep, all we have to do is accept 1 book (or at least your interpretation of it, which changes over the centuries), and ignore all other evidence. But we do have DNA of Neanderthals and other people who lived long before your Adam. Of course, those people are not here to testify that the DNA is theirs, so we can ignore them too.
